# Adding header to .txt file - doesn't iterate through list of files

Tags: python, for-loop, concatenation

My script aims to add headers to some text files that are currently defined in a list.
After that, it should combine the text files into one.

However I'm stuck with this error code here. I wouldn't want to do the same for-loop for every file needed:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/infa/app/ZRH_PCE_DEV/PCE_DATA_ANALYTICS/Scripts/mergerPCE_nodes.py", line 90, in <module>
    for line in fileinput.input([stock_files], inplace=True):
  File "/infa/mgmt/au/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/fileinput.py", line 248, in __next__
    line = self._readline()
  File "/infa/mgmt/au/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/fileinput.py", line 336, in _readline
    os.fspath(self._filename) + (self._backup or ".bak"))
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Is it somehow possible to still iterate through the list?

Here is my code:

```
#Locations
merge_directory_name = 'MergedFiles'
input_path = file_home
              #'/infa/app/ZRH_PCE_DEV/PCE_DATA_ANALYTICS/SrcFiles/PCELogs/'
output_path = merged_path
              #'/infa/app/ZRH_PCE_DEV/PCE_DATA_ANALYTICS/SrcFiles/PCELogs/MergedFiles'
#output_name = 'pc_dblatmonstat_merged_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') + '.csv')
output_name = 'nodes_merged.txt'

stock_files = sorted(glob(raw_path + '/*.sccloud.xxx.com_node.log'))
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + 'Getting .log files from', raw_path)
print(*stock_files, sep='\n')


headers = ["Timestamp",
           "Log"
  ]

for line in fileinput.input([stock_files], inplace=True):
    if fileinput.isfirstline():
        print( '\t'.join(headers))
    print(line)


#read in files via list comprehension
content = [pd.read_csv(f, sep='[;]',engine='python') 
           for f in stock_files]
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + 'Reading files')

#combine files into one dataframe
combo = pd.concat(content,ignore_index = True)
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + 'Combining files')



#drop duplicates
combo = combo.drop_duplicates
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + 'Dropping duplicates')

#Create new directory for merged file
#file_home is '/infa/app/ZRH_PCE_DEV/PCE_DATA_ANALYTICS/SrcFiles/PCELogs/'
merge_directory = Path(file_home, merge_directory_name).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "Directory '% s' created" % merge_directory_name)


#write to txt:
combo.to_txt(output_path + output_name, index = False)
print(bcolors.OKGREEN + 'Merged file output to', output_path, 'as', output_name)
print(bcolors.RESET + '')
```

Comment: It is throwing the error on `for line in fileinput.input([stock_files], inplace=True):`. Take a look at fileinput.input: you are feeding it an array of an array of stock_files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stock_files = sorted(glob(raw_path + '/*.sccloud.xxx.com_node.log'))
```

After this line `stock_files` is a list (glob returns a list).

```
for line in fileinput.input([stock_files], inplace=True):
```

In this line you pass `[stock_files]` which is a list within a list. Removing the brackets solves the error.